# Finding $\mathbb{E}(X|X<Y)$ where $X,Y$ are iid $\exp(\lambda)$ random variables

Tags: probability, statistics, conditional-expectation, expected-value, exponential-distribution

**Question:**
$X,Y$ are two independent random variables following exponential distribution with mean $\lambda$.
$Z$ is another random variable which takes value $1$ if $X<Y$ and $0$ otherwise. Find $\mathbb{E}(X|Z=1)$

---

So basically I have to find $\mathbb{E}(X|X<Y)$ which is equal to $$\int x.f_{X|X<Y}(x)dx$$
I am having trouble finding this conditional pdf . I tried $$f_{X|X<Y}(x)=\frac{f_x(x)}{P(X<Y)}= 2f_x(x)$$ and if this is correct then the required expectation is $2\lambda$ but I am not sure if this is the correct way to approach the problem.

Any help would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$E(X|X<Y)=\frac 1 {P(X<Y)} E(XI_{X<Y})=\frac 1 {P(X<Y)}\int_0^{\infty} \int_0^{y} x\lambda e^{-\lambda x} \lambda e^{-\lambda y} dx dy$. Can you take it from here?.

Comment: I couldn't understand how did you get the first equality

Comment: @Prof.Shanku That is the **definition**. $E(X|B)$ is defined as $\frac {EXI_B} {P(B)}$ whenveer $X$ has finite expectation and $P(B) >0$. When $X=I_A$ this reduces to the usual definition $P(B|A)=\frac {P(A\cap B)} {P(B)}$ of conditional probabilities. Note that this definition does not assume that densities exist

Comment: thanks for the explanation, sir!